# Ruby on Rails: link_to action, no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting into Rails and trying to add a "vote" feature on a blog setup from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

In app/controllers/posts_controller.rb I created this:

```
  def incvotes
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.update_attributes(:upvotes => 1 )
    format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Vote counted.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
```

In app/views/posts/index.html.erb I created this:

```
<%= link_to 'Vote', :controller => "posts", :action => "incvotes", :id => post.id %>
```

But the link is giving the error

> No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"incvotes", :id=>1}

I'm missing something here, but not sure what.

rake routes:

```
incvotes_post POST   /posts/:id/incvotes(.:format) {:action=>"incvotes", :controller=>"posts"}
        posts GET    /posts(.:format)              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
              POST   /posts(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
     new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
    edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
         post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
              PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
              DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
   home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
         root        /(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
```

Comment: What does your routes file say regarding posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
= link_to "vote", incvotes_post_path(post), :method=>:post
```

and if that doesn't work, try changing the method to :put

Comment: With that or put, both give the error: No route matches "/posts/1/incvotes"

Comment: do you possibly have a typo in your code? You've got `post.update_attributes` when it should be `@post.update_attributes`. Not sure if that would cause this problem though. Can you post all of your index view and controller code too please? Do you have github account where you can post the code for your model, controller and index view? Perhaps just stick it on pastie. Sorry to be a pain, but something's not right somewhere

Comment: you do definitely have a typo in your incvotes method - it should be `@post.update_attributes` - can't say if this will fix it or not

Comment: That looked like it. Now I'm getting "too few arguments" and if I fix that it should work.

Comment: you have too few arguments when you change it to @post.update_attributes(:upvotes => 1 ) - i'll have a think about this

Comment: Ah nevermind, it was the format.html part that error was from.

Comment: Are you sure in the code you are calling `update_attributes` which takes a hash and not `update_attribute` which takes 2 arguments? You should edit your question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you probably do not have a definition in your routes file for the action you just defined in the controller.  Both an action in the controller and an action in the routes file must be defined for Rails to generate urls correctly.

Your routes file probably has something like this:

```
resources :posts
```

But you want to add more than the standard actions generated by the `resources` keyword, so try something like this:

```
resources :posts do 
  member do
    post 'incvotes'
  end
end
```

This tells routes that you have another action in your posts controller called incvotes that accepts HTTP post requests as long as they are pointed at a member route with the correct action (/posts/14 is a member route, while /posts/ is a 'collection' route).  So you will have a new route probably like `/posts/14/incvotes` that you can post a form to and everything should start working properly.

EDIT:

Actually I guess since you are just adding 1 to an attribute on a model, you don't need a POST action (which are normally associated with posting forms as with `create` and `update`).  To send a post, you might need to change the HTML in the view to include a form and have it post to the correct url. So you can try that, or you can change your routes file to read `get 'incvotes'` instead of `post 'incvotes'`. Sorry for the confusion, hope that helps!

Comment: My routes file did look like that, so I changed it to that and the vote button now gives: No route matches "/posts/1/incvotes"

Comment: Can you from the command-line run `rake routes` and add the output to your question?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server? I believe if you change the `routes.rb` file at all you need to restart your web server for changes to take effect (even if the output of `rake routes` looks right, your web server may not have picked up the changes if it hasn't been restarted yet).

Comment: I just tried restarting "rails server" and Apache, didn't help. Still getting taken to http://domain.com/posts/1/incvotes and the error No route matches "/posts/1/incvotes"

Comment: Edited my answer to give more info on POST vs. GET

Comment: Okay I've changed it to get and now this error occurs: undefined local variable or method `post' for #<PostsController:0xb700bd08>

Comment: Yes, that's because your first line assigns the controller instance variable `@post` but your second line calls `update_attributes` on the locally defined variable `post` - they are not the same thing. `post` is `nil` while `@post` is the post object. Should have caught that earlier, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The `incvotes_post` route only accepts a HTTP POST, and a link always produces a HTTP GET.

Use a form with a button instead (or do a POST using AJAX).

Comment: Almost, the `link_to` documentation states that passing the `:method` parameter as a URL option to link_to dynamically creates an HTML form with post method.  So you can technically use `link_to` to create a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `button_to` instead `link_to`:

In your view:

```
<%= button_to 'Vote', incvotes_post_path(post) %>
```

In your `config/routes.rb` add the route to `incvotes` action as `post`:

```
resources :posts do 
  member do
    post 'incvotes'
  end
end
```

And in your controller, create the `incvotes` action:

```
def incvotes
  # Something
  redirect_to :posts
end
```